# What should be my delete query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need the delete query within this controller

```php
public function del($id)
{
    $x=App\ImageMod::find();

    // $x->where("id='$id'");
    $x->delete();
    return view('show');
}
```

How can I fetch the `id` dynamically and delete it?

Comment: Isn't this enough   $x=App\ImageMod::find($id);   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can delete for eg blog in this way:

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::findOrFail($id);
    $blog->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Blog deleted'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Request` dependency injection. Then, get the `id` property from your route. Then you can access the `id` from the request. Your code would looks like:

**Controller**

```php
public function del(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->id;

    $x=App\ImageMod::destroy($id);

    return view('show');
}
```

And then in **routes/web.php** you should have:

```php
Route::delete('imagemod/delete/{id}', 'App\YourController@delete')->name('imagemod.delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `$id` from your page (ajax or even a direct request) by placing it within the route.  If using **ajax**, something like:

```
$.ajax({   url: "{{url('ImageMod')}}/" + id,  // <-- id from an input, pulling the val()
           type: "DELETE",
           data: {
           _method: 'DELETE'
         },
      success: function (success) { .. }
```

In your **web.php**:

```
Route::delete('ImageMod/{id}', 'ImageModController@destroy');
```

Then, the routing binds that variable to the destroy method:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    ImageMod::destroy($id);

    return 1;  // if going back to ajax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::table('blogs')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete(); 
}
```